# PLSQL issue in installing in my system

Tags: oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Hello I installed PLSQL developer in my system oracle 11g installed i want place tnsnames.ora file but i am unable to find the network folder in oracle app folder please help me regarding this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Need to install Oracle first.
2. Need to set Java path i.e download java goto-->Jdk and Jre and paste the path in environment variables.
3. lnstall `plsql` (Adminstrator).
4. Place *tns.ora* file network.
   Now you can use `plsql`.